# https rewrite not working on frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have the following code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(apply|ssl) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything is working fine. Except for the frontpage. 
If I access https://website.com it won't redirect the site to http//...

If I remove the line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

it works. But then I get problems with my CMS on all https-pages with my php forms (apply/ssl).

Can someone help me? Anything that I'm missing why the frontpage won't redirect to http://?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homepage ( / ) is treated as a directory, you can insert additional condition for it:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* http://website.com/ [R=301,L]`